# 433 Mhz and 403 Mhz interference

Tags: rf

[image]

I mada a circuit using a 433 Mhz transmitter (to transmit a byte stream, continuously for 20 sec, after which transmission stops). I then connected it to a 5V power supply and the transmitter did transmit the required data to the receiver, however I noticed during transmission I could not use my garage door remote to open the garage door (the garage door receiver runs at 403 Mhz). I do have my 433 Mhz transmitter about 4 m away from the garage door receiver. Why is this happening, and most importantly, what can I do the resolve this kind of interference.

I am using these RF chips as my transmitter (Left pic) and receiver (Right pic). Has anyone used these chips before, if so what problems did you encounter, if any

Comment: How do you know your garage door opener operates on 403MHz.  433MHz is one of the few allowed frequencies for garage door openers - 403MHz is not.

Comment: I opened the receiver box of the garage door and it was imprinted on the PCB.

Comment: The regulatory requirements for ISM band usage state that you cannot continually transmit for 20s. IIRC the limit is 5s.

Comment: Thank you Steve G, I was not aware of this restriction, as I am still learning about how wireless communication operates in the real world conditions.

Comment: @Joey a brief summary is [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra048/swra048.pdf).

Comment: "Why is this happening?". Probably because the garage door receiver has such poor selectivity that it also picks up the 433MHz signal, which blocks the 403MHz from the garage door transmitter.

Comment: @Joey - what country are you in?  Regulations vary throughout the world.  Most of the world supports one of two specific frequencies around 433MHz with various restrictions including the one mentioned by Steve G.

Comment: @Joey - are you sure you are not misreading the frequency? It could also be as suggested by SteveG as the super-regenerative receivers often used in garage door openers have very poor selectivity - I would have thought 30MHz away would have been ok.  Try moving your transmitter further away  from the receiver.

Comment: It is likely your Garage door Rx has some crude AGC, so even though you are many MHz away, you are physically close and overloading the GD Rx. What RF power are you using for the 433 MHz application?

Comment: Kevin White: I am from South Africa

Comment: Jack Creasey: RF power is 10mW

Comment: Quite possibly, your transmitter could also be spewing out spurious emissions outside the designated band. Without some screenshots from your spectrum analyser, nobody will be able to answer the question. (Run it with max hold for a minute or so to catch all noise.)

Comment: For those questioning 403MHz, it does seem that there are a fair few devices on that frequency for the SA market. Based on [this](http://www.southernyachting.co.za/uploads/8/1/2/9/8129491/icasa_notice_890_of_2008.pdf), 403MHz in SA is licensed for various short-range devices, including ([this, p11](http://internet.org.za/26193.pdf)) garage door openers. For EU or US the band is reserved for various purposes including active medical implants.

Comment: "Use your spectrum analyzer to ...": I wish I had one of these Rohde & Schwarz lying unused in my garage, too.

Comment: *"I opened the receiver box of the garage door and it was imprinted on the PCB."* Are you sure that was the actual operating frequency? It could be an intermediate frequency (although I admit I'd expect that to be in the few megahertz to several tens of megahertz range, not a few hundred megahertz...).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling- Yes, im sure because the transmitter is also running at 403 Mhz for the garage door(The 403 MHz was also imprinted on the transmitter PCB).